# Using boost::pool to manage the memory allocations in a std::vector

Tags: c++, boost, vector, allocator, boost-pool

I want to have a `std::vector` of objects, with the objects allocated using `boost::pool`. Is something like this correct:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    double data;
public:
    MyClass(double d) : data(d) {  }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<MyClass, boost::fast_pool_allocator<MyClass> > vect;
    vect.push_back(4.5);
    vect.push_back(9.8); //Are these being stored in a pool now?

    return 0;
}
```

This code works, but I'm not entirely sure why. I am quite new to the concept of allocators, but if I understand correctly this is telling `std::vector` to use a pool instead of the default allocator, so any elements created in the vector will be created from a pool.

What I'm not exactly sure of, is:

Where is the pool?

And how would I access the pool directly (to free memory for example)?

Does `fast_pool_allocator` contain a pool, or do I need to create the pool separately and somehow tell the allocator to use it.

Comment: You might want to read e.g. [this `std::vector` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). I'm sure you can find a suitable function to get the allocator. You might also want to check out the [`std::vector` constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

Comment: The [boost reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost/fast_pool_allocator.html) says to use `boost::pool_allocator` with `std::vector`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of `boost::fast_pool_allocator` the pool is a singleton owned by the allocator implementation. So you do not need to create anything separately.

You can access the allocator via `get_allocator` function of `std::vector`, or you can use static functions in `boost::fast_pool_allocator`.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [boost reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost/fast_pool_allocator.html), there is a singleton instance of the allocator that is used by all. You can use it to allocate memory as well as free it, just by creating a local `boost::fast_pool_allocator` or `boost::pool_allocator` object.